# is it possible to work with multiple 9-patch images at the same time?

Tags: android, image, nine-patch

I am developing an app for android, in this app there are 30 pictures that need to be stretched for multiple screen resolution. every 10 of them have exactly the same 9-patch borders.

So here we can specify it for only 1 picture,
but I have 10 pictures with exactly same sizes, but different colors.

[image: 9Patches picture]

Is there any solution to work on 10 pictures at the same time ? because they already will have the same 9-patch.

Comment: work on them at a time? what does it mean?

Comment: sorry still unclear to me

Comment: @pskink I mean, usually you do 9patch for each picture separately, dont you? you draw that border on the picture letting it stretch when needed. The same border that we draw, in my case, with exactly the same sizes of borders, is applied to 10 pictures.

Comment: how i draw border? where? what picture are you talking about? be specific, otherwise nobody will answer you

Comment: @pskink do you know 9patch ?

Comment: of course: its NinePatchDrawable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76038/discussion-between-mbh-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm guessing you just want to save yourself the work of applying the 9patch another 9 times. you sure could automate that, but i doubt it's worth the time if it's really an one-time job.

if this is recurring work, i'd write two small cmdline tools:

- Script A: extract the 9patch-part from a png (just copy the outermost lines) and save it to a file
- Script B: 9patch-part file and apply it to an existing png file

let them work with parameters so they can be scripted easily.

it'd be easy in java and you already know the language. estimated time for both: around 30 mins to an hour.

remember: "9-patches" are nothing else than a 1 pixel border in a completely normal PNG image file where the color is either transparent (do not scale) or black (do scale).

Comment: that is exactly the answer for my question !

Comment: so i may copy the 9patch from one picture, and apply it to the other 9 pictures. That will be a nice tool for android developers. Thank you for clear answer

Comment: just copy only the outermost pixels. and be sure that the image sizes are matching!